# Nativescript app. Difficulties with displaying items in the XML

Tags: nativescript

I am building an app with Nativescript. Displaying RSS posts.

I have some difficulties how to show the parsed object in the XML.

Here is my rss-list-view-model.js

```
var observable = require('data/observable');
var ObservableArray = require('data/observable-array').ObservableArray;
var fetchModule = require('fetch');
var config = require('../config');

function handleErrors(response) {
    if (!response.ok) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
        throw Error(response.statusText);
    }
    return response;
}

exports.empty = function() {
    while (feedItems.length) {
        feedItems.pop();
    }
};

exports.load = function name(params) {
    console.log('CALLING LOAD');
    //handle caching
    if(feedItems.length > 0) {
        console.log('leaving early');
        return;
    }

    return fetch('https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20title%2Clink%2Cdescription%20from%20rss%20where%20url%3D%22'+encodeURIComponent(config.rssURL)+'%22&format=json&diagnostics=true', {
    })
    .then(handleErrors)
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
    }).then(function(data) {
        console.log('number of rss entries: '+data.query.results.item.length);
        data.query.results.item.forEach(function(feedItem) {
            feedItems.push({
                        title: feedItem.title,
                        link: feedItem.link,
                        description: feedItem.description
                    }
            );
        });
    });

}

var feedItems = new ObservableArray();
exports.feedItems = feedItems;

var viewModel = new observable.Observable();
exports.viewModel = viewModel;
```

And here is my main-page.xml:

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" navigatingTo="loaded">

    <Page.actionBar>
        <ActionBar title="{{ title }}" />
    </Page.actionBar>


        <ListView items="{{ rssList.feedItems }}" itemTap="loadItem">
            <ListView.itemTemplate>
                <Label text="{{ title }}" horizontalAlignment="left" verticalAlignment="center" />
            </ListView.itemTemplate>
        </ListView>
</Page>
```

When i dump my objects in this function its shows them in the console.

```
.then(function(data) {
        console.log('number of rss entries: '+data.query.results.item.length);
        data.query.results.item.forEach(function(feedItem) {
            feedItems.push({
                        title: feedItem.title,
                        link: feedItem.link,
                        description: feedItem.description
                    }
            );
        });
```

And here is my main-page.js

```
var RssListViewModel = require('../shared/view-models/rss-list-view-model');
var frameModule = require('ui/frame');

var config = require('../shared/config');

var Observable = require('data/observable').Observable;
var viewModule = require('ui/core/view');
var page;

var pageData = new Observable({
    rssList:RssListViewModel,
    title:config.title
});

exports.loaded = function(args) {
    page = args.object;
    page.bindingContext = pageData;
    RssListViewModel.load();
};

exports.loadItem = function(args) {
    //rssList.viewModel.set('selectedItem', args.view.bindingContext);
    RssListViewModel.viewModel.set('selectedItem', args.view.bindingContext);
    frameModule.topmost().navigate('views/item-page');
}
```

Why cant display them in the view?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you bind the model to the view, the items have not yet been fetched and therefore there is nothing to render.

To solve this there are many ways, one of which could be the following:
1) Have the `load` method of the `rss-list-view-model.js` return a Promise.
2) In the `loaded` method of `main-page.js` do something like :

```
RssListViewModel.load().then(function(data){
    page.bindingContext = pageData;
});
```